# JSON form api parse

Tags: json, flask, request

I would like to ask if someone could help me with the issue I had below:

I tried to parse a JSON object from a external api to mysql and I am not able to success.

The JSON object looks like below:

```
[
   {
      "id":1234,
      "programId":1234,
      "programName":"hhhh",
      "code":"hhhh",
      "updateDate":"1435722826346",
      "publishStartDate":"1435701600000",
      "publishEndDate":"1439675999999",
      "startDate":"1435701600000",
      "endDate":"1439675999999",
      "title":"SEK 47.00 off SEK 430.00 \t",
      "shortDescription":"SEK 47.00 off SEK 430.00 \t",
      "description":"SEK 47.00 off SEK 430.00 \t",
      "voucherTypeId":1,
      "defaultTrackUri":"http://hhhhh.hhhhh.com/hhhh?a(hhh)p(hhh)ttid(hhhh)url(http://www.hhhhh.com/sv)",
      "siteSpecific":false,
      "landingUrl":"http://www.hhhh.com/sv",
      "discountAmount":47.0,
      "isPercentage":false,
      "publisherInformation":"",
      "languageId":"sv",
      "exclusive":false,
      "currencyId":"SEK",
      "logoPath":"http://hst.hhhhh.com/file/hhhhh/100x35.jpg"
   }
]
```

The code I used to access the info is:

```
url = url[2]
    try:
        json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url).read
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        return "Connection Error"  
    voucher_json_list = json.loads(json_obj)
    return json.dumps({'message':''+voucher_json_list['code']+''})
```

However I am not able to get the info to fetch it to the DB.

Could anybody could give me some lights on this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant:

```
try:
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
except: ...
```

Also, does the data really contain `"id":hhhh,`? because hhhh is not valid and will raise a parse error.

I think it would be cleaner to do:

```
try:
    json_obj = json.load(
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
    )
except urllib2.URLError:
    ...
except ValueError:
   # invalid JSON
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually the id field will have some int value and it didn't work is giving me  Invalid **JSON object**